# What is the best data type for an array like structure in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that stores tracks and I want to add sector times for each track. Each track could have a different number of sectors, the same track will always have the same number of sectors and the sector times can not exist for some tracks.

When retrieving the data I would like to get the lowest sector time for each sector for a given track as well.

The best idea I could come up with is to have a json object with `sector1`, `sector2`, ... etc. This is ok but it requires the code retrieving the data to know the number of sectors to `SELECT` it, like in the example below. This means that "number of sectors" would also need stored.

```
CREATE TABLE test (track TEXT NOT NULL, sectors TEXT);
INSERT INTO test (track, sectors) VALUES ('track1', json_object('sector1', 10, 'sector2', 11, 'sector3', 12));
INSERT INTO test (track, sectors) VALUES ('track1', json_object('sector1', 11, 'sector2', 9, 'sector3', 12));
INSERT INTO test (track, sectors) VALUES ('track1', json_object('sector1', 10, 'sector2', 9, 'sector3', 12));
INSERT INTO test (track, sectors) VALUES ('track1', json_object('sector1', 12, 'sector2', 12, 'sector3', 4));
INSERT INTO test (track, sectors) VALUES ('track2', json_object('sector1', 12, 'sector2', 12, 'sector3', 3, 'sector4', 1));
INSERT INTO test (track) VALUES ('track1');
select * from test;
select min(DISTINCT json_extract(sectors, '$.sector1')), min(DISTINCT json_extract(sectors, '$.sector2')), min(DISTINCT json_extract(sectors, '$.sector3')) from test where track = 'track1';
```

Is there maybe a better way to store data like this and to be able to `SELECT` it like I stated above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the data into two tables:

```
create table tracks(trackid);
create table sectors(trackid, sectorid, times);

insert into tracks values('track1');
insert into tracks values('track2');

insert into sectors values('track1', 'sector1', 10);
insert into sectors values('track1', 'sector2', 11);
insert into sectors values('track1', 'sector3', 12);
-- etc

select min(times) from sectors where sectorid='sector1'
```

Add primary-foreign key as you see fit.

Comment: I think this is probably a better approach and more performant than parsing JSON lots of times